# Visual modeler in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mit-scratch, visual-modeler

I'm working on a project in which I have to build a modeler in C#. There's a tool on which I want to base the modeler of, namely Scratch. Scratch implements a drag-and-drop feature with which you can build a diagram that consists of blocks that 'fit' into each other - like a lego concept. Are there any providers that have a tool/component that supports such a feature? If not, what is the best way to go about achieving it?

This is an example of a diagram built in Scratch:

http://progopedia.com/static/upload_img/2011/02/18/scratch-camelcase.png

Thanks in advance!

Greets,
Vincent

Comment: You can do that with an `ItemsControl` in WPF. It looks like an interesting and fun challenge, though. If I have some time today, I'll create a small example for you. I don't know of any (free or commercial) libraries that will do that for you

Comment: Answers go in answers :)

Comment: yes, as @AntP said, please put your update as an answer

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's been more than a year since I posted the question but I'll post how I solved it anyway.

There's a very useful modeling library called MindFusion. Link: http://www.mindfusion.eu/ While this does provide the basics for creating a modeling tool, you will have to implement everything else yourself, from custom shapes to events etc. But using this is still way better than have to create the fundamentals yourself. Note: the support on that website is very good too!

Hope this helps